# newbie --> How to deploy my jsr 168 portlet inside liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Three simple questions...

**Question 1.**

I have a JSR168 portlet that is deployed over IBM Websphere Portal server at my company. I was using a  version of IBM Portal server for my development but strictly speaking I don't think I am allowed to use these at my company. So now my plan is to do my development and testing on my local machine using liferay and then deploy to IBM Portal Server.

From what I have read about liferay since it supports jsr168 I should not have any problems. Is this correct?

**Question 2.**

I've just finished installing the liferay 6.2-5 stack on my mac from the Bitnami site. It is running but I am having troubles understanding how I can deploy my first portlet (which by the way works under IBM Portal Server).

After logging in I go to Admin> Control Panel> Apps> App Manager. I then hit Install and select my war file and then put in a context root. But I keep getting an error message "Please enter a valid url".

What is the problem here?
[image]

**Question 3.**
After the Portlet has been installed how can I see it in liferay?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 1: correct, Liferay supports JSR-168

for 2: You can either drop your WAR file in Liferay's "deploy" folder, which will cause Liferay to deploy it from there. If it disappears from that folder within a few seconds, it has been deployed.

The administrative UI allows you to do a similar thing through the Web UI - you can either upload your plugin or point to a URL where Liferay can download it: Don't mix it up with Websphere's admin UI where you give the context name for an uploaded application. In Liferay you'll either have to use the upload OR the URL. The context name is derived from the name of the WAR file.

for 3: You'll find your plugin when you choose the "Add" button - login as Administrator and you'll find a "+" labelled button on the left side of the screen. Choose "Application" and look for your portlet (you can filter the list). If you include some Liferay-specific deployment descriptors (look up WEB-INF/liferay-display.xml) you can also influence which section/headline it appears under.

Comment: thanks so much for your comments. I've followed your instructions to install the porlet by using control panel > app manager > install and that worked. However when I click on the "+" sign my application does not appear in the list. Is that because liferay-display.xml is not there?

Comment: I've check in my project into github just in case you wanted to see https://github.com/rriviere/StockOnHand . Again appreciate your help as I'm a newb.

Comment: actually ignore this. I have just been looking at the logs and can see that I have an exception when liferay is loading my portlet. I am going to accept your answer even though I'm not quite there yet. thanks, this helped me greatly!

Comment: Ok, thanks. You might want to start a new question for your exception problem if you can't figure it out by the nature of the exception.